# Finding the rows with the minimum value per group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by

How do I get the min timestamp value of the same Id number with its corresponding Value using SQL?

Would anybody help me with this problem?
(Please see attached image below)

**Sample Table**

[image]

**Sample Table of what should be the result**

[image]

Comment: instead of image please post the data OR create sqlfiddle

Answer (score 2):

Filter the data based on [RANK (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms176102(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
declare @temp as table
(
    employeeCode  varchar(11) not null, 
    TimeStamps datetime not null, 
    Value varchar(9) not null
);

insert into @temp 
    (employeeCode, TimeStamps, Value)
values 
    ('A021','2015/08/25 11:39:02.937','3000'),
    ('A021','2015/08/25 11:39:02.937','Monthly'),
    ('A021','2015/09/02 13:18:42.630','3200'),
    ('A021','2015/09/02 13:18:42.630','Monthly'),
    ('ACK00005','2015/06/09 15:15:45.970','12000'),
    ('ACK00005','2015/06/09 15:15:45.970','Monthly'),
    ('ACK00005','2015/06/09 16:17:37.420','15000'),
    ('ACK00005','2015/06/09 16:17:37.420','Monthly'),
    ('PA001','2015/06/09 15:15:45.970','10000'),
    ('PA001','2015/06/09 15:15:45.970','Monthly'),
    ('PA001','2015/06/09 16:17:37.420','12000'),
    ('PA001','2015/06/09 16:17:37.420','Monthly'),
    ('PAPH0001','2015/06/09 15:15:45.970','5000'),
    ('PAPH0001','2015/06/09 15:15:45.970','Monthly'),
    ('PAPH0001','2015/06/09 16:17:37.420','8000'),
    ('PAPH0001','2015/06/09 16:17:37.420','Monthly'),
    ('PAPH0002','2015/06/11 17:05:41.720','5000'),
    ('PAPH0002','2015/06/11 17:05:41.720','Monthly');
```

The solution involves ranking the rows in the desired Timestamps order, giving ties the same rank, and restarting the numbering when the employeeCode changes. We return rows that rank #1:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
        rnk = RANK() OVER (
            PARTITION BY T.employeeCode
            ORDER BY T.TimeStamps)
    FROM @temp AS T
)
SELECT 
    CTE.employeeCode,
    CTE.TimeStamps,
    CTE.Value
FROM CTE
WHERE CTE.rnk = 1;
```

Output:

[image: Results]

For more general 'n' rows per group problems, please see:

[Retrieving n rows per group](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group)