# Three table query to find the most recent item based on a distinct value

Tags: sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I am attempting (without success thus far) to write a query that will join 3 tables and return the most recent record based on a distinct value.

**Table A**

```
itemnum  | itemname
-------- | --------
123      | document #1  
456      | document #2
```

**Table B**

```
itemnum  | keyvaluedate
-------  | ------------- 
123      | 2015-09-05 00:00:00.000  
456      | 2011-06-04 00:00:00.000  
789      | 2011-06-04 00:00:00.000  
546      | 2011-06-04 00:00:00.000  
378      | 2011-06-04 00:00:00.000
```

**Table C**

```
itemnum  | keyvaluebig 
-------- | -----------
123      | 123456  
456      | 123456  
545      | 987654   
387      | 987654
```

Table A holds all of the records. What I need to find is the most recent record (keyvaluedate from table b) for each distinct project (keyvaluebig from table c).

The itemnum data is always unique. The keyvaluedate from Table B and the keyvaluebig from Table C both non-distinct values present.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns the row from `table A` that relates to the most recent record in `table B` for each `keyvaluebig` in `table C`

Setup:

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE
(
    itemnum INT
    , itemname NVARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT @TableA (itemnum, itemname)
VALUES (123, 'document #1'), (456, 'document #2');

DECLARE @TableB TABLE
(
    itemnum INT
    , keyvaluedate DATETIME2
);

INSERT @TableB (itemnum, keyvaluedate)
VALUES (123, '2015-09-05 00:00:00.000'), (456, '2011-06-04 00:00:00.000')
,(789, '2011-06-04 00:00:00.000'), (546, '2011-06-04 00:00:00.000')
,(378, '2011-06-04 00:00:00.000');

DECLARE @TableC TABLE
(
    itemnum INT
    , keyvaluebig BIGINT
);

INSERT @TableC (itemnum, keyvaluebig)
VALUES (123, 123456), (456, 987654), (545, 987654), (387, 987654);
```

Query:

```
WITH cte_Numbers
AS
(
    SELECT  c.keyvaluebig
            , b.itemnum
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.keyvaluebig ORDER BY b.keyvaluedate desc) AS RowNumber
    FROM    @TableB b 
    JOIN    @TableC c ON b.itemnum = c.itemnum
)

SELECT  a.*
FROM    @TableA a
JOIN    cte_Numbers n ON a.itemnum = n.itemnum
WHERE   RowNumber = 1
```

As mentioned by Mark Sinkinson [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group) really is the place to go to see how to do this sort of stuff