# Return the most recent event in a series of same title events

Tags: sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I need to be able to return the most recent event of a occurrence that may or may not have occurred more than once. For instance:

Each time a product is moved from position A to Position B, it is recorded (From_Function) / (To_Function) along with its operator and timestamp.
On rare occasions, re-work is required, and that unit will show the same from / To instance with different timestamps.

I am currently calculating age in each position with a datediff,  how do I return only the most recent in this scenario?

I got it down to if there is no group by clause it will return the date needed with a max(route_date_time); however, the total qry is many lines long with aggregate functions so a group by is necessary. How can I return only the one line that is needed with the most recent date?

Comment: Please edit the question and add more details (i.e exact table structure, sample data, wanted output, the query you have so far.) Even better, a small [SQLfiddle](https://www.sqlfiddle.com) with all that.

Comment: What's your SQL Server version?

Comment: Here's a good place to start: http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: It seems that your question is the same as: [Retrieving n rows per group](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an item moves between some type of state or location (`From_Function`, `To_Function`) and the timestamp of the move is in the `route_date_time` column, you could put your query in a common table expression, along with a `ROW_NUMBER()` function that calculates a sequence number, like so:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT item_no,
           ToFunction AS current_function,
           route_date_time,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
               PARTITION BY item_no
               ORDER BY route_date_time DESC) AS _rownum
    FROM some_complex_query
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE _rownum=1;
```

Because we've partitioned the `ROW_NUMBER()` function on `item_no` and ordered it by `route_date_time` descending, `_rownum=1` will always return the most recent row for each `item_no`, which is what we're isolating using the `WHERE` clause at the end of the query.

If you need the time that each item has spent in a state, you could use `LAG()` (requires SQL Server 2012 or newer). Within the CTE, use the following expression:

```
    DATEDIFF(second,
             LAG(route_date_time, 1) OVER (
                 PARTITION BY item_no
                 ORDER BY route_date_time),
             route_date_time
            ) AS time_spent_in_function
```

This will return the difference in number of seconds between the *previous* `route_date_time` (the `LAG()` function) and the current `route_date_time`. Bear in mind the `PARTITION BY` clause, which defines how you partition your records.