# TSQL speedup partition by query

Tags: sql-server, performance, window-functions, query-performance

```
CREATE TABLE entries(
  uuid            BINARY(16) PRIMARY KEY,
  status          VARCHAR(20),
  client_id       VARCHAR(32),
  creation_date   DATETIME,
);
```

status can be NEW, IN_PROGRESS, DONE

I need one entry with status != DONE for each client_id. I want maximum 500 of such entries and with oldest creation date.

I ended with query:

```
SELECT TOP (500) * 
FROM (SELECT 
          *, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY client_id 
                             ORDER BY creation_date) rn 
      FROM entries 
      WHERE status <> 'DONE') v 
WHERE rn = 1
```

We have around 1000 clients and around 1 milion entries. 
Currently query executes ~90 seconds on our Azure SQL database.

Azure SQL Server suggested creating following index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [nci_wi_entries_0A6FBEBB67742F72F54C5F86FD2C5023] 
ON [dbo].[entries] ([status]) 
INCLUDE ([client_id], [creation_date]) 
WITH (ONLINE = ON)
```

After that, query executes around 20 seconds, but that is still too slow. I must have results in less than second.

Do you have any ideas how to optimize it (in any way, either rebuilding table or optimizing query)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a separate table `Clients` with the list of all 1000 client IDs, it may be faster to seek 500 times into 1M rows table instead of reading all 1M rows. This is another common variant to write a `top-n-per-group` query. The following question discussed it in great details: [Retrieving n rows per group](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group).

Also, use filtered index to match your query:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX] ON [dbo].[entries]
(
    [client_id] ASC,
    [creation_date] ASC
)
INCLUDE 
(
    [status], 
    [uuid]
) 
WHERE (status <> 'DONE')
```

The query (assuming you have `Clients` table):

```
SELECT TOP(500)
    CA.*
FROM
    dbo.Clients
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1)
            dbo.entries.*
        FROM
            dbo.entries
        WHERE
            dbo.entries.client_id = dbo.Clients.client_id
            AND dbo.entries.status <> 'DONE'
        ORDER BY dbo.entries.creation_date
    ) AS CA
;
```

Comment: It works really great, single query time is about  50 ms. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using [Indexing for Windowing Functions: WHERE vs. OVER](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/09/indexing-windowing-functions-vs/) by [Erik Darling](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/32281/sp-blitzerik), the following indexes helped us to reduce query time to about 200 ms:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX entries_index 
ON dbo.entries (client_id, creation_date ASC) 
INCLUDE (status, uuid)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX inverted_entries_index 
ON dbo.entries (status) 
INCLUDE (client_id, creation_date, uuid)
```