# JOIN only latest row through a pivot table in one to many relation - MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables and I only need to compare data between 2 of them but only taking in mind the latest row. The structure of the table is as follows

**Table Places**

| id | brand | phone | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Place A | 000000 | email@domain.com |
| 2 | Place B | 000000 | email@placeb.com |
| 3 | Place C | 000000 | email@placec.com |

**Table Offers**

| id | name | vendor_phone | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 234 | Offer A for Place B | 00000000 | $1000 |
| 235 | Offer B for Place B | 00000000 | $900 |
| 236 | Offer C for Place B | 00000000 | $950 |
| 237 | Offer A for Place C | 00000000 | $500 |

**Pivot table**

| id | place_id | offer_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 234 | NOW() |
| 2 | 2 | 235 | NOW() |
| 3 | 2 | 236 | NOW() |
| 4 | 3 | 237 | NOW() |

Basically I wish to craft a query where I could take all the places data (places.*) joined with the latest offer (offer.*) data in 1 row.

When I join regularly I get a lot of duplicate rows. If I use GROUP BY statement I am not guaranteed to join the latest offer data from the offers table. Pivot tables confuse me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving n rows per group](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group) In MySQL you can use the `ROW_NUMBER` solution

Comment: Side note: what you call a Pivot table is not, it's just a many-to-many join table

Comment: Maybe you should look at [group_concat_ws](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11889564/470530)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query:

```
SELECT p.*, o.* 
FROM places AS p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT place_id, MAX(offer_id) AS latest_offer_id
    FROM place_offer
    GROUP BY place_id
) AS po ON po.place_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN offers AS o ON o.id = po.latest_offer_id
;
```

will output:

| id | brand | phone | email | id | name | vendor_phone | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Place B | 000000 | email@placeb.com | 236 | Offer C for Place B | 00000000 | $950 |
| 3 | Place C | 000000 | email@placec.com | 237 | Offer A for Place C | 00000000 | $500 |
| 1 | Place A | 000000 | email@domain.com | null | null | null | null |