# SQL query to join on maximum value on a per-row basis

Tags: join, query, subquery

I'm stuck writing a query for the following scenario: I have a table of things, they have a metric called `number` in the examples below. I have another table called `offers` which is a list of offers made on a particular thing. I'm looking for the **highest offer on each thing that is less than or equal to the `number` on a thing**.

I can't seem to come up with the right `JOIN` and `MAX()` to satisfy the query, and end up running in circles.

`things` table:

| id | number | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | Thing 1 |
| 2 | 10 | Thing 2 |
| 3 | 8 | Thing 3 |

`offers` table:

| thing_id | offer | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | thing 1 offer 1 |
| 1 | 3 | thing 1 offer 2 |
| 1 | 12 | thing 1 offer 3 |
| 2 | 9 | thing 2 offer 1 |
| 3 | 1 | thing 3 offer 1 |
| 3 | 8 | thing 3 offer 2 |

Desired output:

| thing_id | number | offered | thing_description | offer_description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 3 | Thing 1 | thing 1 offer 2 |
| 2 | 10 | 9 | Thing 2 | thing 2 offer 1 |
| 3 | 8 | 8 | Thing 3 | thing 3 offer 2 |

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving n rows per group](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group)

Answer (score 1):

You could try along

```
select
  x.thing_id,
  x.numbr,
  x.offered,
  x.thing_description,
  o.description as offer_description
from (
  select
    t.id as thing_id,
    t.numbr,
    max(o.offer) as offered,
    t.description as thing_description
  from Things t
  join Offers o
    on t.id = o.thing_id
    and t.numbr >= o.offer
  group by t.id, t.numbr, t.description
  ) x
join Offers o
  on x.thing_id = o.thing_id
  and x.offered = o.offer
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/036221/1)

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.